# Design Pattern to connect heterogeneous components

Tags: c++, design-patterns

**Introduction**:
I need to create a module in c + + / Qt software that stores user actions as a kind of macro. Each business(macro) step is implemented as component  with some inputs and outputs.

**Problem**: 
An interface (architecture) that allows generated macro steps to communicate using output and inputs from each step (Business components) combined as required.

**Question**:
Can you please suggest examples or patterns to solve this problem?

Comment: Pipe and Filter style?

Comment: The pattern for linking a number of components together is a linked-list :p     In your case, why not embed Lua, Javascript or Python, and let scripting take the hard work off you?

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-implemetation step**: Before doing the system design make a Finite State Machine Diagram for your System dtailing each state(macro) and the input and output. This would also help you in designing the business layers associated with each macro.

**Implementation Step**: I would recommend using a combination of 2 patterns - 
1. State Pattern - because each your application will need to be in a specific state(i.e. undergoing execution of a specific macro) at a time.
2. Then use a command pattern to handle the execution of each state(macro in this use case). When using the command pattern each macro will have its own handles to business logic and will transition to the next state based on the business result.